# Retrieving an Object through Serialization

Tags: java, string, object, serialization

I am trying to seriliaze an Object having a reference to another Object as instance variable. I follow the common way, nevertheless I cannot retrive in the main() method the second Object (which is non Serializable). Here is my Code:

```
 public class Car {

String type;
int speed;

public Car(String s, int v){
    type = s;
    speed = v;
}
```

}

```
public class Employee implements Serializable {

String name;
int Id;
transient Car car;

public Employee(String s, int i, Car c){
    name = s;
    Id = i;
    car = c;
}

private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream os){
    try {
        os.defaultWriteObject();
        os.writeObject(car);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream is){
    try {
        is.defaultReadObject();
        car = (Car)is.readObject();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

In the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Car c = new Car("noType", 100);
    Employee e = new Employee("Aris", 1, c);

    try {
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream("save.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fo);
        out.writeObject(e);
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }


    try {
        FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("save.txt");
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fi);
        Employee emp = (Employee) in.readObject();     // Comment
        System.out.println(emp.car.speed);
        in.close();
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

On the line "Comment" in the second try block it throws a nullPointerException. It cannot save the Car object this way. What should I do to get over it? Ofcource I want necessarily the Car class to remain non-seriliazable. If prefer to save the instrance variables of the Car object and to recreate it by the aid of them and its constructor, how can I save (and retrieve) the String attribute?

**UPDATE:**

When trying to save only the int instance variable, it works. The relevant methods are this time:

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream os){
    try {
        os.defaultWriteObject();
        os.writeInt(car.speed);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream is){
    try {
        is.defaultReadObject();
        car = new Car("theNew", is.readInt());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But my question is still how (or if) I can save the entire object. After all I did not manage to save and retrieve the String. WriteString(), ReadString() methods 
do not exist.

Comment: May we know why you want the Car not be serializable, when at the time you are trying to serialize it or at least deserialize it?

Comment: This only an example code. Suppose that I don 't have access to class, so I cannot modify its code.

Comment: Ok, so it's not that you wouldn't **want** it's that you **cannot** make it serializable. But you could write a serializable Class that takes all of the parameters, right? And on serialization you serialize that one instead. On deserialization you create a Car from that substitute?

Comment: see my answr below, use os.writeObject();

Comment: updated my answer again with full code

Comment: @AlexWien: I accept your answer because you dealt with it thoroghly, but I still not consider it as a targeted answer to my problem, taking into account the steps and your claims till reaching to its ending form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
car = (Car)is.readObject();
```

is wrong.
Car is not Serializable.

Solutions:

1. make car serializable, and remove the line
2. Use a MyCar object which is Seriazable only for the purpose of ser/ deser,  and create car from MyCar, see point 3.
3. create a new Car : car = new Car(); but where to get the data from? (see point 2)
4. seialize the fields of car, one by one using os.writeObject() and for primitives e.g os.writeInt();
5. use your own custom serialization, using DataOutputStream

**Update** answer to your update question

String is an object, you serialize it with os.writeObject(car.type);
See also [ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html)
Code using solution 4:

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream os){
    try {
        os.defaultWriteObject();
        os.writeObject(car.type);
        os.writeInt(car.speed);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private void readObject(ObjectInputStream is){
    try {
        is.defaultReadObject();
        String type = (String) is.readObject();
        int speed = is.readInt();
        this.car = new Car(type, speed);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think defaultReadObject refers to the Employee object. This object (e) I am trying to save and retrieve.

Comment: @AlexWien : the Car class is transient doesnt matter if it is not serializable

Comment: @Bhavik Shah you are wrong, the second time now, so please remove your downvote: a class is never transient!!, the member car is transient, which does not play a role in self serialisation as he does!

Comment: @AlexWien : The OP is trying to store Employee object to the file not Car. since the Car variable in Employee object is transient it doesn't matter whether the class Car is serializable or not

Comment: Anyway class Car CANNOT be seriliazable. That is the point of my question. How could someone implement properly the methods readObject(), writeObject() to retrieve the Car. I am almost sure it can be done. I show in my Update that with a simple int variable it works.

Comment: @BhavikShah wrong the third time, he uses overidden serialisation, and can do what he wants. e.g reading 2 objects from stream and crewte a new Car from that both objects. transient is used in default write/read object

Comment: @AlexWien : I'm revoking my downvote since you are so heated up, but I still disagree with your answer :) . we are all friends here buddy :)

Comment: I tried it, but while trying in readObject() method to recreate the Car through car = new Car((String)is.readObject(), is.readInt());, it does not work. In main() it throws still a NullPointerException.

Comment: do not inline coding, this is never good, mske it one line afetr another, first read int, them read string, then create object. the same in write. first write int,nthen write string

Comment: Aside from not using inline code, the key of this issue is that sb must get the attributes though readxxx() in the order they save them. Othewise they come across an Exception. It is one of the few occassions in Java, that the order plays role. I cannot accept though your answer (AlexWien) as correct as you persisted in making the class Car Serializable, which annuls the purpose of my question. I share the opinion of BhavikShah. I beleive his comments were correct, although the first one was not expressed properly.

Comment: @arjacsoh i never insisted in making Car serializble, i posted 5 solutions. see my post. yes the order is important, like in all computer programms. only in key value based files (xml) it is not important.